Pause routing in react native, don't add a route to stack until a variable is true
In my messaging application, I have a variable isBiometricSuccessfull, when it becomes false, I route to biometrics screen. It is checked in Home component.
const HomeComponent = () => {
    const { isBiometricSuccessfull } = useHomeHook();
    const navigation: any = useNavigation();

    useFocusEffect(() => {

        if (!isBiometricSuccessfull && navigation.isReady()) {
            navigation.navigate('biometricsScreen');
        }
    });

   
    return (
           <HomeStackNavigator.Navigator
                screenOptions={{
                    headerShown: false,
                    animation: 'slide_from_right',
                }}>
                 .
                 .
                 .
           </HomeStackNavigator.Navigator>

         );
};


When I am on biometrics screen I have prevented going back.
useEffect(() => {
        BackHandler.addEventListener(ANDROID.hardware.event.hardwareBackPress, preventGoingBack);
        return () => {
            BackHandler.removeEventListener(ANDROID.hardware.event.hardwareBackPress, preventGoingBack);
        };
    }, [isBiometricSuccessfull]);

    function preventGoingBack(): boolean {
        return !isBiometricSuccessfull ? true : false;
    }



The issue arises when any other screen is pushed in navigation stack from any other hook.
For example, when user is on biometrics screen and clicks on a message notification from notification panel, it will route the user to chat route.
I want to prevent all type of routing from this biometrics screen.
I also want to resume the routing once isBiometricSuccessfull becomes true. Which means, continuing the above example, I want to route to chat once variable is true.
I have tried these react native navigation events, but these also seems not to pause routing.
Please guide me, please also tell if there possible improvement in my logic.
Thanks.

you can make complete different stack for the biometrics and when you got successfully get the biometrics then you will update the state to true otherwise its will be false through this no other screen can navigate. after getting access you can switch the stack.

By conditionally rendering the stack, I will loose track of where the user was, whenever biometrics screen comes.

if you dont want to loose your track then you can use modal insted of switching stack. or you can you can use
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-exit-app this.
when user exit or performe a back action this will kill the app insted of allowing him to move forword or before that you can show that you must pass the biomatics

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You can add a condition wherever you're handling the routing if the current route is biometrics Screen and isBiometricSuccessfull is false then it shouldn't do anything and else continue with the usual routing. But you'll have to use useContext or redux to pass the isBiometricSuccessfull variable globally.

Yes, isBiometricSuccessfull is a global state.
By this flow you have mentioned, I will have to check isBiometricSuccessfull everywhere there is routing.
Also, I want to resume desired route when isBiometricSuccessfull becomes true. I will have to keep track of where the route wanted to go when isBiometricSuccessfull was false.

I usually use a function and call it for routing, you can check for the route in that function.

Yea, but I was wondering If react native would provide some event to prevent/pause routing, like they have given event to handle back press.
